# Given a biregular graph, how to find the maximum edge complete bipartite/biclique subgraph with a given number of vertices on one side?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, bipartite

For example,I have a biregular graph G(E,L∪R).The problem is I'd like to find the maximum edge  complete bipartite subgraph K(E',S∪T) with a given cardinality of S or T.Please recommend relevant literature to me soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a straightforward reduction from clique-finding, making this NP-hard and hard to approximate.

Comment: Very appreciate！It's a helpful answer for me!